# Difference between Selenium version 2.46 from 2.48 when it comes to finding elements with same ids

Tags: selenium

When it comes to finding elements in a page that has more then two same ids, is there a difference between Selenium version 2.46 from 2.48 ? Ideally selenium  2.46 version finds first instance of the element that has the same id in page. How does selenium 2.48 behave?

In my tool i updated selenium jar libraries form 2.46 to 2.48 and got some issue with respect to finding elements with same ids.

Below is my code... the codes job is to determine "a" element which is inside some element.

```
    WebElement ul4 = driver.findElement(By.id(AdDimension));
    List<WebElement> allOptions4 = ul4.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (WebElement li4 : allOptions4) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        li4.click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Action : Ad Dimension Id Selected");
    }
    }
```

This works well if i use 2.46 ..... i.e it clicks on "a" element.

then the same code doesn't work if i use 2.48

Comment: What is the error that you got?

Comment: "some issue" ? what exactly went wrong or is different?

Comment: Below is my code... the codes job is to determine "a" element which is inside some element.

  WebElement ul4 = driver.findElement(By.id(AdDimension));
  List<WebElement> allOptions4 = ul4.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
  for (WebElement li4 : allOptions4) {
   Thread.sleep(500);
   li4.click();
   Thread.sleep(500);
   System.out.println("Action : Ad Dimension Id Selected");
  }
  }
This works well if i use 2.46 ..... i.e it clicks on "a" element. 

then the same code doesn't work if i use 2.48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Selenium changelog there should not be any changes for the object identification.
[Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

Try finding the same element with a different browser. Sometimes your specific browser versions may have a issue the 2.48 version

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 

Yes, selenium has not changed their object identification method. i realized  that the problem is occurring due to something else.

Comment: Below is my code... the codes job is to determine "a" element which is inside some element.

  WebElement ul4 = driver.findElement(By.id(AdDimension));
  List<WebElement> allOptions4 = ul4.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
  for (WebElement li4 : allOptions4) {
   Thread.sleep(500);
   li4.click();
   Thread.sleep(500);
   System.out.println("Action : Ad Dimension Id Selected");
  }
  }
This works well if i use 2.46 ..... i.e it clicks on "a" element. 

then the same code doesn't work if i use 2.48

Comment: There are multiple "a" elements inside the ul4 element. Are you sure it is not clicking on any of the elements? How many elements are you getting for the allOptions4  list?

Comment: Hi, there is only one "a" element inside ul element. If I use 2.46 version of selenium the code works perfect but if I use new version I.e 2.48 version then "a" is not clicked.